# iterating through a json object/dictionary

Tags: python, json, loops, dictionary, iteration

```
abc = {
"orders": [
    {
        "orderID": 5,
        "cost": 10,
        "sell": 15
    },
    {
        "orderID": 6,
        "cost": 8,
        "sell": 12
    },
    {
        "orderID": 7,
        "cost": 15,
        "sell": 26           
        }
    ]
}

for key, value in abc.items():
print (value["orderID"])
```

I am trying to extract the orderID values, but cant seem to make this work.  It should respond with
5,6,7

Comment: start by printing `value`, and look what it returns...

Answer (score 2):

right now you're looping over the `abc` dict. Instead, you want to loop over `abc['orders']`:

```
for order in abc['orders']:
    print (order["orderID"])
```

Comment: Are you sure that your code matches your statement? ;)

Comment: Whoops that was pretty stupid... thanks

Comment: Worked!!!  Thank you

Comment: Great. If your problem is solved you should accept one of the answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
for d in abc['orders']:
    print (d["orderID"])
```

`abc` has a key `orders` which is a list.So you can iterate over the list.